# $firebaseAuth().$getAuth() returns a null

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

```
var firebaseUser = $firebaseAuth().$getAuth();
if (firebaseUser) {
console.log("Signed in as:", firebaseUser.uid);
} else {
  console.log("Signed out");}
```

returns a `null` after I refresh the page 2 times, even though the user is still logged in. And if I get the UID of the Firebase User to add some data on my real time database, since it's `null`, my app will have an error

Answer (score 3):

to get the current user you should do this:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

Or you can handle the auth:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

All this info are from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?hl=es)

Comment: i used this onAuthStateChanged many times before but sometimes it messes up my app specially when updating my database and i use it to get the current user. One thing i would really like to know would be getting the user object and use it outside the onauthstatechange

Comment: you can get the user object with the first code section

Comment: Note that you should only refer to `currentUser` **after** you've handled at least one `onAuthStateChanged` as initially, this property will be `null` until your app completes the connection to Firebase

Comment: @Phil's comment is very important, I ran across this issue and didn't realize the connection does not get established before `currentUser` is populated with data